# Health Check for instance that doesn't accept incoming connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a server that doesn't accept inbound connections, it simply reads from a queue and does some processing when there are items in the queue.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way for me to do something like a reverse health check. Perhaps there would be a health check server that the queue server has to ping every 10 seconds. If the health check server doesn't receive a ping for 30 seconds then it would trigger an alarm state and send me an email.

Is there a relatively straight-forward way for me to set-up something like this? Or should I be thinking of a different way to test the health of this instance?

Comment: Depends on the constraints you have.  You can implement a heat beat like you described which does exactly that - send a ping every X time, then you can monitor what its pinging to make sure it been refreshed. Since you already have it checking and reading the queue - you can log after each check and monitor the log.  Lots of monitors that are able to be configured to read  logs. Describe your constraints a little more and we can post a potential answer.

Comment: I don't really have constraints, I can open up a port and run a web server if needed but I was hoping that there might be more lightweight of doing it. I thought there might be an AWS service that lets you send out a heartbeat and will send you a notification if it doesn't hear anything for some period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would include a simple php/nginx service on the instance. Add a default index.php that checks the service, logs, or other check according to your needs. Return an http status of 200 if all is good, or a 500 if any of the checks fail. Include a diagnostic error message on the 500 error response so you can quickly see the source and nature of the error. You can then expose the http endpoint as a health check.

Works great for nearly any custom service or process that you need to monitor that do not accept incoming tcp or http connections.